# RJDBC hive, connect failed

Tags: hive, rjava, rjdbc, cdsw

I followed multiples tutorials to try to connect to Hive with RJDBC, without sucess.

Here is what I have:

```
library(DBI)
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)


driver <- JDBC('org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver',
            classPath = list.files("/home/cdsw/R",pattern="jar$",full.names=T),
            identifier.quote="`")

USERNAME <- "MyUser"
PASSWORD <- "MySecretPassWord"
HOSTNAME <- "my.host.net"
PORT <- 10000

server <- sprintf('jdbc:hive2://%s:%s', HOSTNAME, PORT)

conn <- dbConnect(driver, server,
                  USERNAME, PASSWORD)
```

I have downloaded and place at `"/home/cdsw/R/"` the `jar` files.

```
list.files("/home/cdsw/R",pattern="jar$",full.names=T)

[1] "/home/cdsw/R/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.16.99.jar"
[2] "/home/cdsw/R/hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.16.99.jar"
```

I've also tried most recent versions, but always sync with the same Cloudera Version. Even if my version is 5.XX.

I'm quite sure the `HOSTNAME` is correct since I've made it work with `impyla` in Python with the same Hostname/port.

The Error:

> Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/TException

From what I understand, I don't have the correct `.jar`s?

Remark:

I can not install hive-jdbc on the machine since I'm not root. Can I do without it since I have place the 
`hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.16.99.jar` in a folder?

Also, could Kerberos trigger this error?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to download the standalone version of the hive driver.

`hive-jdbc-3.1.2-standalone.jar`, the standalone version does not require the full install of hive client.